# How to test controller layer on spring-boot by autowiring service?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, controller

I am trying to test the functionality of my controller in my API. I have implemented the following service called `ExpertsServiceImpl.java`:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExpertsServiceImpl implements ExpertsService{

    private final ExpertRepository repository;



    @Override
    public Experts createExpert(Experts expert) {
        return repository.save(expert);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteExpert(ObjectId id) {
        Experts deleted = findExpertById(id);
        if(deleted == null) {
            throw new ExpertNotFoundException(id);
        }
        repository.delete(deleted);
    }
    public Experts findExpertById(ObjectId id) {
        Optional<Experts> searchedExpert = repository.findById(id);
        if(searchedExpert.get() == null) {
            throw new ExpertNotFoundException(id);
        }
        return searchedExpert.get();
    }
```

This is my `MongoDB` repository:

```
public interface ExpertRepository extends MongoRepository<Experts, ObjectId>{

}
```

And this is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@Validated
class ExpertController {

    public final ExpertsService service;
    public ExpertController(ExpertsService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }


    @PostMapping(path = "/experts/",
              consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
              produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
           )
    public Experts newExpert(@Valid @RequestBody Experts newExpert) {
        return service.createExpert(newExpert);


    }

    @DeleteMapping("/experts/{id}")
    public void deleteBook(@PathVariable  ObjectId id) throws Throwable {
        service.deleteExpert(id);
    }
```

I am writting the following test class for my controller:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ExpertController.class)
class ExpertControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ExpertsService expertsService;

    @MockBean
    private ExpertRepository repository;

    Experts demoExpert = new Experts(ObjectId.get(),"Steve Jobs", "Enterpreneur",
                                     Availability.BUSY, Language.CHINESE);

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
        expertsService.deleteAll();
        expertsService.createExpert(demoExpert);

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception{
        expertsService.deleteAll();
    }


    @Test
    public void deleteExpert() throws Exception {
        String expertId = demoExpert.getId();
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .delete("/experts/{id}", expertId)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
```

Which throws this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
```

Does anyone understand how I could fix this? I guess it has to do with the fact that I am autowiring the Service and Mocking the repository, but not sure how to fix this. I would like to autowire the Service as mocking it wouldnt make much sense for my tests. Anyone knows how I could go about this? I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

`WebMvcTest` only initialise the Controller layer so all service/repository beans are not created and injected. In your case the problem is

```
@Autowired
private ExpertsService expertsService;
```

Replace with

```
@MockBean
private ExpertsService expertsService;
```

Now you have mock for your service and you can focus on testing the Controller logic only.

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment! As mentioned above, I dont wanna mock my service. I wanna autowrire it in order to make the tests

Comment: The goal seems to test the Controller layer so I would mock the service and then verify the interaction with the mock (verify a method is called or not).

If you want to autowire the service then your test should be annotated with `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to mock the service, you can add `@Import(ExpertsServiceImpl.class)` on top of your test class or use `@SpringBootTest` as mentioned (but in this case it will load the whole application, which is not really great, performance-wise)